# Lightning Page Error Message: "No metadata was retrieved for ..."

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package

We're working with Steelbrick which is a managed package and I'm struggling with an error message which is surfacing now we have deployed to Production.

The error message says "No metadata was retrieved for field SBQQ__QuoteLine__c.Formula" which looks like a FLS issue to me - however I've been unable to recreate by removing FLS access to the field I suspect in our dev sandbox.

Has anyone encountered an issue like this previously and have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the CPQ version ( compare it with other org where it is working ), the field used in Price Action formula may not be available for this CPQ version.

Note: This is applicable only if you are using Package field in the formula. Local custom fields do not throw error unless the Target Object selected has the all fields used in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the CPQ version in Production is compatible with the field SBQQ__QuoteLine__c.Formula. Sometimes, managed packages might have field definitions dependent on specific CPQ versions. Inconsistency between versions can lead to such errors.

While FLS seems unlikely in your case, double-check if the formula in SBQQ__QuoteLine__c.Formula depends on other fields. Missing FLS access to those dependent fields might also cause this error.

Answer (score -1):

The issue turned out to be related to a errant Pricing Rule trying to populate a field with the text value "Formula", hence the random error message.

Comment: Can you [edit] this answer to be more detailed? As it stands, I wonder how much this would help someone else who had the same issue.

Comment: I ran into a similar error "No metadata was retrieve for field SBQQ__QuoteLine__c.Some_Field__c". There were price actions that were referencing fields that were not deployed as expected. After creating the fields, the error still persisted, which was because the value at the product level was null and couldn't twin to the quote line. The formula on the price action did not want to work with a null number.